# Creating iOS app with two "modes" (UIViewController and UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to create an iOS app that has two distinct modes that I will switch between programmatically. The modes are:

- Mode 1: A custom `UIViewController` in which I show some information (text, images and a table view - not important for this question). Think of this mode as the "list of magazines".
- Mode 2: A `UINavigationController` on which I can add/remove view controllers. Think of this mode as "browsing a single magazine (a magazine with multiple pages)".

What is the recommended view hierarchy for this app?

For example, should I create a `UIPageViewController` at the top-level, nesting into it the `UIViewController` (mode 1) or `UINavigationController` (mode 2)?

Or should I create a `UINavigationController` at the top-level instead of a `UIPageViewController`? (For mode 2, this would mean that a `UINavigationController` is nested within a `UINavigationController`.)

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you'd plan to transition between mode 1 & 2. but it sounds like mode 1 is a `UITableViewController` (or `UIViewController` with a tableView) and mode2 is it's 'DetailsViewController', in this case i would embed mode1 in a `UINavigationController` and push/pop mode2 onto it